# JS expression to calculate the average value of all given data points within a month, for all months represented in the data points

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, expression

I'm looking for an JavaScript expression to calculate the average value of all given data points within a month, for all months represented in the data points. So far I've only thought to hard code new arrays for each month and add to them with 12 conditionals, then average the values of each list. But I feel like there certainly must be a cleaner more efficient way.
sample data = (eg. [YYYY, MM, DD, Value] ) :

```
[
  [ 2020, 1, 2, 1058 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 8, 1055 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 12, 1058 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 23, 1049 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 24, 1050 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 29, 1057 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 1, 1088 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 5, 1087 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 13, 1101 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 26, 1108 ],
  [ 2020, 4, 25, 1119 ],
  [ 2020, 8, 24, 1178 ],
  [ 2020, 8, 25, 1196 ],
  [ 2020, 9, 29, 1214 ],
  [ 2020, 9, 31, 1230 ],
  [ 2020, 10, 20, 1259 ],
  [ 2020, 11, 18, 1276 ]
]
```

The first three fields are dates (YYYY, MM, DD) *jan-dec is represented as 0-11*, and the last field is the value that will be averaged.

The return I'd want from the expression would be an array of the monthly averages (eg. {month: average value} ):
[{1: avg}, {2: avg}, {4: avg}, {8: avg}, {9: avg}, {10: avg}, {11: avg}]]

Comment: could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @hgb123 All that I have tried is what I mentioned, making an array for each month, and then iterating thru the original array to add the the values to the corresponding array, then calculating the average of each.

Comment: although that way works, It seems very inefficient and inelegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  [ 2020, 1, 2, 1058 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 8, 1055 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 12, 1058 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 23, 1049 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 24, 1050 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 29, 1057 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 1, 1088 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 5, 1087 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 13, 1101 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 26, 1108 ],
  [ 2020, 4, 25, 1119 ],
  [ 2020, 8, 24, 1178 ],
  [ 2020, 8, 25, 1196 ],
  [ 2020, 9, 29, 1214 ],
  [ 2020, 9, 31, 1230 ],
  [ 2020, 10, 20, 1259 ],
  [ 2020, 11, 18, 1276 ]
];
let result = [];
let result2 = arr.reduce((res, [year, month, day, value]) => {
  if (!res[month]) {
    res[month] = { month: month, avg: 0, count: 0, sum: 0 };
    result.push(res[month])//remove this if you are satisfied with the result in result2;
  }
  res[month].sum += value;
  res[month].count +=1;
  res[month].avg = res[month].sum/res[month].count;
  return res;
} , {});
console.log('array of objects {[month, sum, count, avg]}', result);
console.log('object with values {month: {month, sum, count, avg}}', result2);
```

Just chose whichever result suits you best!

Here you go my man, it maybe could be done cleaner but if you want something more, ill get back to you when it is not 6 in the morning! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with George's solution but here's another way to achieve what you want to do with lots of comments.

```js
let source = [
  [ 2020, 1, 2, 1058 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 8, 1055 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 12, 1058 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 23, 1049 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 24, 1050 ],
  [ 2020, 1, 29, 1057 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 1, 1088 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 5, 1087 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 13, 1101 ],
  [ 2020, 2, 26, 1108 ],
  [ 2020, 4, 25, 1119 ],
  [ 2020, 8, 24, 1178 ],
  [ 2020, 8, 25, 1196 ],
  [ 2020, 9, 29, 1214 ],
  [ 2020, 9, 31, 1230 ],
  [ 2020, 10, 20, 1259 ],
  [ 2020, 11, 18, 1276 ]
];

// Object to store our output
let averages = {};

// Loop through the source data
source.forEach(row => {
  // Create an array as this month's value if not set
  if (!averages[row[1]]) 
    averages[row[1]] = [];
  
  // Lump the same-month values into the correct array. Use parseInt to avoid
  // potential NaN errors
  averages[row[1]].push(parseInt(row[3], 10));
});

// Calculate the averages by looping through each key in the object (each month),
// using reduce to get the sum of the array and then use the length property to
// get the average of that array.
Object.keys(averages).forEach(
  (m) => averages[m] = averages[m].reduce((v, i) => v + i, 0) / averages[m].length
);

// TADA!                            
console.log(averages);
```